# Django Rest Framework - & on method filter not working as expected

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**My Models:**

```
class Detail(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table = detail
```

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
    qty = models.IntegerField()
    
    @property
    def from_detail(self):
        return Detail.objects.filter(id=self.id).values('entry_date')

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table=item
```

In my filterset I am doing the below:

```
class ItemFilter(FilterSet):
    entry_date__gte = DateTimeFilter(field_name='entry_date', method=entry_gte_filter)
    entry_date__lte = DateTimeFilter(field_name='entry_date', method=entry_lte_filter)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('name', 'qty', 'entry_date__gte', 'entry_date__lte')
```

**For some reason I have to use the method field here and cannot give the lookup expr directly**

My methods look like below:

```
def entry_gte_filter(queryset, name, value):
    name = f"{name}__gte"
    queryset = Item.objects.annotate(
        detail=models.Exists(Detail.objects.filter(
            **{name: value, 'id': models.OuterRef('id')}))).filter(detail=True)

    return queryset
```

and

```
def entry_lte_filter(queryset, name, value):
    name = f"{name}__lte"
    queryset = Item.objects.annotate(
        detail=models.Exists(Detail.objects.filter(
            **{name: value, 'id': models.OuterRef('id')}))).filter(detail=True)

    return queryset
```

However, when I execute the below API:

`GET /api/items?entry_date__gte=2021-06-29&entry_date__lte=2021-07-04`

I get the responses with below entry dates:

```
2021-06-30T00:00:00
2021-06-11T00:00:00
2021-07-02T00:00:00
```

I am unclear why a response with 2021-06-11 is being returned when the API mentions entry_date__gte=2021-06-29

To me it looks django filters is not working as expected when method type is used. Could anyone please help me here why djangorestframework is behaving like this and if there is any way to fix this and get the expected behavior?

Comment: Could you share definitions of `Item` and `Detail` models?

Comment: @wiaterb Models added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the requested view is configured correctly and the `ItemFilter` filter and it's methods (`entry_lte_filter`, `entry_gte_filter`) are executed then I see two reasons it does not work.

Firstly, in every filter method you start off with a new queryset (`Model.objects`). You should use the `queryset` provided as parameter and return result of amending it, [docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#filter-method).

Secondly, you try to compare `datetime` field (`entry_date`) with a string that represents a `date`. You can compare them when you use `__date` [lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date).

```py
def entry_gte_filter(queryset, name, value):
    name = f"{name}__date__gte"
    queryset = queryset.annotate(
        detail_date_gte_exists=models.Exists(Detail.objects.filter(
            **{name: value, 'id': models.OuterRef('id')}))
    ).filter(detail_date_gte_exists=True)

    return queryset
```

and

```py
def entry_lte_filter(queryset, name, value):
    name = f"{name}__date__lte"
    queryset = queryset.annotate(
        detail_date_lte_exists=models.Exists(Detail.objects.filter(
            **{name: value, 'id': models.OuterRef('id')}))
    ).filter(detail_date_lte_exists=True)

    return queryset
```